# Recieving user integer, storing, then printing it MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I can accept user input:

```
addi $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, str.num2
syscall
addi $v0, $zero, 5
syscall
add $s1, $zero, $v0
```

It's in $s1, I just don't know how to get that printed out. How can i do that?

Comment: What are those syscalls? SPIM emulator syscalls?

Comment: I'm using MARS to code, if that's what you mean

Answer (score 7):

[Here](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html) you have a reference for syscalls in MARS. Following this, the code should go:

```
# Print message (syscall 4)
addi $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, str.num2
syscall

# Read number (syscall 5)
addi $v0, $zero, 5
syscall

# Print number (syscall 0)
add $a0, $zero, $v0  # Get number read from previous syscall and put it in $a0, argument for next syscall
addi $v0, $zero, 1   # Prepare syscall 0
syscall              # System call
```

Always comment your code, specially if it's assembly.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, and yeah I know I have I just didn't want to clutter up my message.

Comment: Glad it worked. Comments would make us understand much faster what you do and what you want to do :)

Comment: okay so I'm starting to grasp this a bit better. I'm using branches within this program and the number I wish to be displayed has been previously entered and store in $s1. How would I print out the $s1, rather than the newly entered integer? Sorry :( (I've been playing about with it myself - I can code in java - but I just can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: That's normal, assembly has nothing to do with Java (which is a higher level language). Use `add $a0, $zero, $s1` instead of `add $a0, $zero, $v0`. The number printed is the one in $a0 as specified in the link I gave you before.

Comment: Awesome, it's working. Thanks so much for you help. When I'm printing the numbers though, it's (assume the number is 134) it'll print 134134-134. I really feel needy asking all these questions, but if you could answer this I'd be forever greatful